# A foundational question about harmonic motion: 2 pipes with different length and frequencies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, resonance, harmonics

How to solve the following question?

> **A pipe open only at one end has a fundamental frequency of 256Hz. A second pipe, initially identical to the first pipe, is shortened by cutting off a portion of the open end. Now, when both pipes vibrate at their fundamental frequencies, a beat freqency of 12Hz is heard. How many centimeters were cut off the end of the second pipe? The speed of sound is 343m/s.**
> *The ans is 1.5cm.*

Using the formula :$L=\left(\frac{2n+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{v}{f}\right)$

The length of the first one $=\left(\frac{2\left(1\right)+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{343}{256}\right)= 1.0048828m$.

Then, The frequency of second one $= 256 + 12 = 268Hz$

Therefore,  the length of the second one $=\left(\frac{2\left(1\right)+1}{4}\right)\left(\frac{343}{268}\right) = 0.95988806m$

The length difference $= 1.0048828 - 0.95988806 = 0.04499474m = 4.499474cm$

How to calculate the right answer?

---

***Thank you for your attention***

Comment: Put n=0. Wikipedia article on acoustic resonance gives formula with n not 2n+1, but it's said that n must be odd starting from 1. This is of course equivalent. So in your version first possible resonance is for n=0 not n=1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Jarosław Komar commented, you are using the wrong value for $n$. It is also easy to visualize this by looking at what the longest standing wave would look like in an air column with only one open end:
[image]
Where the [wavelength](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength), $\lambda$, is defined as:
$$
\lambda=\frac{v}{f}
$$
So the fundamental frequency would require a $n=0$, since the length of the air column would have to be $\frac{1}{4}\lambda$.

---

Note that in the above diagram the nodes and antinodes represent the pressure inside the column. However, many illustrations online use the displacement of the medium inside the column, instead of the pressure. This results in [flipping the nodes and antinodes](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/LongitudinalStandingWaves/), so a pressure node is a displacement antinode and vise versa. This is because the displacement is proportional to the change of pressure with respect to position.

Comment: @nerak99 the diagram is correct, if one is considering pressure instead of displacement. I have updated my answer with this clarification.

Comment: @nerak99 Not if the figures show the nodes and antinodes in acoustic pressure. This is the parameter used to describe sound waves more often than particle displacement

Comment: @nasu I stand corrected and would have edited my comment but I could only delete it. I a quick survey of text books, many have both versions of the diagram. Where there is only one diagram the particle displacement version is usually given

Comment: @nerak99 but your confusion is an understandable one, since many diagrams don't actually state which of the two (pressure or displacement) they are displaying. So having this discussion in the comments might help clear this confusion for someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't state that the second pipe emits 12 Hz higher, but that the beating is at 12 Hz. In this situations, because the frequencies are close, a beating phenomena occurs stemming from the sum (fast beating) of frequencies or the subtraction (slow beating) of them.

One of these two beating frequencies is the one reported and from here you have to find out the second note frequency and from that the length of the pipe or the difference in lengths.

Comment: if the subtraction of frequencies gives the slow beat frequency as you say then surely the second pipe does emit 12Hz higher?

Comment: Yes, don't know what I was really thinking at that time.